# Show info window google marker external click with coffeescript

Tags: google-maps-api-3, coffeescript

Hi there I've a problem with getting an external link to work with coffeescript and google maps.

I've tried as many solutions as i can't figure out why the info window isn't showing

```
jQuery(document).ready ($) ->

  if $('#map').length > 0
    marker = google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    $('#map').after('<a href="#"  id="open-marker"><span class="icon-icons_arrow-right"></span>open info window</a>');
    $('#open-marker').on 'click', ->
      google.maps.event.trigger marker, 'click'
      return

initialize = ->

  pos = undefined
  positionFound = false
  latlon = new google.maps.LatLng(50.5913444,8.7154506)
  #icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
  #  settings.marker_icon
  #)

  style = [{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":40}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"saturation":-10},{"lightness":30}]},{"featureType":"landscape.man_made","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"},{"saturation":-60},{"lightness":10}]},{"featureType":"landscape.natural","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"},{"saturation":-60},{"lightness":60}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"},{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":60}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"},{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":60}]}]

  mapOptions =
    zoom: 15,
    center: latlon,
    styles: style

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions)
  contentString = "<h4>Info window</h4>"
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(content: contentString)
  marker = new google.maps.Marker(
    position: latlon
    map: map
    title: ""
    icon: icon
  )

  google.maps.event.addListener marker, "click", ->
    infowindow.open map, marker
  return marker
```

The browser shows no error.
The settings marker icon is added via wordpress localize script -> the icons shows up and the marker click function works also.

```
    wp_enqueue_script( 'scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/app.js', array(), '20120206', true );

  $settings = array('marker_icon' => get_template_directory_uri().'/images/map-marker.svg');
  wp_localize_script('scripts', 'settings', $settings);
```

Comment: I don't know what your settings.marker is... or your map div... please provide minimum workable code(html, javascript) so I can reproduce your error.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pf0wj7f0/2/ this is what I'ive got the marker icon is irrelevant right now

Answer (score 0):

so I've translated your coffeescript to js and created [**jsfiddle project**](http://jsfiddle.net/pf0wj7f0/). Your code seems right and infowindow works great except for the variable `icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(settings.marker_icon);` where settings is not defined... Your infowindow works perfectly fine when I commented out the icon line. The error seems to be that settings is not defined.

Comment: I've tried to explain it more in depth with the edit i've just made